# Check if member is boosting server

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I wanted to check if a Member is boosting and how much they have boosted the server. Any way to do so? I know you have the `GuildMemberUpdateBoostTimeEvent` but that doesn't allow me to check how much a certain individual has boosted the server. Does anyone know?

(Only methods the `GuildMemberUpdateBoostTimeEvent` has are `e.getNewTimeBoosted()` and `e.getOldTimeBoosted()`)

Comment: Discord does not expose the number of boosts per member in their api

Answer (score 0):

There is also Member.isBoosting().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).